Why have all photos of some folders turned black in any application but show up when copied to places higher up in the tree or other devices?
From one day to another, I cannot view the pictures of some chosen directories.
Windows-Fotoanzeige = Windows Photo Viewer shows a black window:

Greenshot as another picture application does not even pop up at all.
In other directories, I can view the pictures with both applications. The pictures have the size that they should have, and I know that I could view them on my Desktop before I sorted them away into the folders they are now in.
Following All my photos have turned black unable to view them - Microsoft Community - Windows 8, you need to copy or move the images or their folders.
Copying without changing the places does not help:

I tried it with a copy of an image into the same folder (giving the suffix "(copy)").
I tried it with a copy of the full folder into the same place (giving the suffix "(copy)").

It does help copying files or folders to other places "further away" (another computer, another dummy folder further up in the explorer tree).
Now that I know this workaround, I still wonder what is going on here. I do not want to break my sorting of files by workarounds. And I do not want to follow workarounds for something as easy as showing an image. Instead, I want to know how I can fix this or what is leading to this black out of images.
Why have all photos of some chosen folders turned black in any picture application but show up when I copy them to places higher up in the explorer tree or to folders in other devices?

Path length
The length of the path over the whole tree from parent to leaf folder is too long for Windows.

When I shorten the name of the parent folder only a bit like from:

To:

..I can view all pictures again. And this is reproducible, I can go back and forth with always the same outcome.
Path length against filepath length
Cutting the filename instead of the folder name, I find that this does not work at all: cutting is not allowed for that picture, even if I cut the folder name to where I can show the picture. I see from this that the path length is already too long for any edit, so that Windows checks the filepath, while the application loads the path on its own and the filename on its own.
And I can prove this by pasting a picture with a shorter name (changed from roughly 30 to 1 letter), it still shows up dark:


This proves that only the length of the path (folder tree) leads to the blackout in the picture viewer, not a too long filepath.
Allowed Windows path length up to 260
With backslashes, the too long path that leads to the blackout and blocked renaming has a length of 226. Going down character by character, at a path length of 216 (with the drive name "K:" and two other "" backslashes, so 5 characters less perhaps if backslashes are not escaped "\", not important enough to check it further), I can edit the filenames and show the pictures again.
Checking that on the net, I find that it is 260 in the end:
Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?
This must come from the nature of my "K" drive which in reality is an AD directory on another server, and Windows seems to count both server name and technical AD directory as well to reach 260.
The same link also has an answer about how to mount a folder as a drive, therefore, mapping the long technical device name and the Active Directory - and perhaps even more subfolders - can help freeing space for the path name.
